# Apache default page displayed for zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Well I install Zabbix 6 on ubuntu 20.04 LTS with mysql and nginx
Deviation from the link below
https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=6.0&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=20.04_focal&db=mysql&ws=nginx
I have stopped Apache and the site is serving using nginx

I did not install default zabbix nginx as it was installed and configured earlier as well

I am getting a error of Apache Ubuntu test page

Can anyone throw light on what I am missing

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your Apache configuration.

Comment: Hello Gerald I am not using Apache as webserver and using nginx The default file looks like this 
server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name  monitor.xirify.com;
        client_body_in_file_only clean;
        client_body_buffer_size 32K;
        client_max_body_size 300M;
        sendfile on;
        send_timeout 300s;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
            location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.36.159.44;
            }
        }

Comment: Please edit the configuration in your question, it's unreadable in the comments.